# advice for adding an element from local storage to a dropdown menu in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Main Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
.newStyle1 {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color: #0000FF;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}
.newStyle2 {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
.newStyle3 {
    color: #0000FF;
}
.newStyle4 {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #0000FF;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="newStyle2" onload="disableOnLoad()">
<script>
function disableOnLoad() {
    document.getElementById("dropList").disabled = true;
}//on page load drop down list is disabled

function clickStore() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {   
        if(localStorage.weblink1){      
            document.getElementById("dropList").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = localStorage.weblink1//links retrieved
            document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = localStorage.weblink2
            document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = localStorage.weblink3
            document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = localStorage.weblink4
            document.getElementById("e").innerHTML = localStorage.weblink5      
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "These websites have been stored in local storage.";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("dropList").enabled = false;
            localStorage.weblink1= "www.yahoo.com";//links set to webpage text
            localStorage.weblink2= "www.cnn.com";
            localStorage.weblink3= "www.reddit.com";
            localStorage.weblink4= "www.mnsu.edu";
            localStorage.weblink5= "www.youtube.com";
            //document.getElementById("buttonclick").disabled = true;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }//setelement id 
}

function getStore(value) {  
    window.open("http://" + value);//should retrieve from local storage 
}

function addStore() {
    var input = document.getElementById("inputtext");//get text from user input 
    localStorage.setItem("Text1", input.value); //place in local storage

    var select = document.getElementById("dropList");//create variable select from droplist
    var option = document.createElement("f");//create new element f
    option.innerHTML = localStorage.Text1;//assign variable to local storage input
    select.add(option);//add variable select to droplist with local storage input

    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "This website is added to local storage";
}
</script>
<p><button id="buttonclick" onclick="clickStore()" type="button" class="newStyle1">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result" class="newStyle3"></div>
<form method="post">
    <input id="inputtext" name="Text1" type="text"><input class="newStyle1" name="Button1" type="button" value="Add" onclick="addStore()"></form>
<div id="result2" class="newStyle3"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>
    <div class="newStyle3">
        Click a link from the dropdown box to go to the site.</div>
</div>
<br>
<label>Dropdown list</label>
<select name="dropList" id="dropList" onchange="getStore(document.getElementById(this.value).innerHTML)" class="newStyle4">
  <option value="a" id="a"></option>
  <option value="b" id="b"></option>
  <option value="c" id="c"></option>
  <option value="d" id="d"></option>
  <option value="e" id="e"></option>  
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code so far. I am trying to get an item that is through user input and store it in local storage and then add it to an existing drop down menu in html. I am trying to do this around the function addstore(). I am able to get the element to be stored in local storage but am having trouble adding it to the dropdown menu. Any advice for doing this? should the dropdown list be hard coded in HTML or should it be created in javascript for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var option = document.createElement("f");
```

should be changed to:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
```

It's not related to local storage

Comment: If I wanted to make the new link in the dropdown clickable, so if I entered a url then it would go to that webpage, how could I add it to the existing code? For the hardcoded links, I used "onchange" and did window.open in the getStore function.